# How Do I group in Mongoose for categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Data :

I have category , Sub category 1 and sub category 2. I am storing each category by using parent_id. And the following is my data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b550"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "category" : "ewb",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-01-09T06:55:57.376Z"),
    "parent_id" : null,
    "status" : "Y",
    "type" : "Column"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b551"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "category" : "wealth",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-01-09T06:55:57.378Z"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b550"),
    "status" : "Y"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b552"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "category" : "hh economic well-being",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2019-01-09T06:55:57.379Z"),
    "parent_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b551"),
    "status" : "Y"
}
```

Now I have to print as

```
Category : [{
  category : 'ewb',
  "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b550"),
  sub_cat1 : [{
    category : 'wealth',
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b551"),
    sub_cat2 : [{
      category : 'hh economic well-being',
      "_id" : ObjectId("000000005e712c388852b552"),
      }]
    }]
}]
```

Without changing the schema How do I achieve this. I refered SO

Comment: A nice $aggregate or get all data in js and build the array